# How to decode malformed string in PHP

Tags: php, iconv

I have a database full of encoding errors, and am at a loss trying to reverse to find the original data.

This is a sample address from Turkey.

```
MÃ?Â¼ze MÃ?Â¼dÃ?Â¼rlÃ?Â¼Ã?Å¸Ã?Â¼
KonyaltÃ?Â± Cad.
MuratpaÃ?Å¸a
Antalya
```

**Update**

The problem was two-fold.

1. Corrupted characters in the original `latin1_swedish_ci` tables. i.e. characters falling outside of the charset.
2. Double utf-8 encoding during phpMyAdmin export/import.

A solution for the latter appears to be:

```
$str = str_replace('?', chr(194).chr(131), $str);
$str = utf8_decode(utf8_decode($str));
```

This does not solve the original corruption problem, that encoding information has been lost as suggested by @cleong

Comment: `MuratpaÃ?Å¸a` should be `Muratpaşa`, so `Ã?Å¸` = `ş`

Comment: Can you show your relevant table schema and collation?

Comment: The database collation is `latin1_swedish_ci` and I believe it may have been imported/exported from phpMyAdmin as `utf-8` 1 or more times in the past.

Comment: The data looks too damaged to be repaired. The text seems to have been misencoded a couple time. The question marks indicate some bits have gotten lost.

Comment: It's possible that there's still a one-to-one correspondence between the gibberish sequences and the original letters. If you carefully study the pattern you might be able to build a mapping table that reconstruct much of the original text.

Comment: @cleong Looks like a mapping table is an option, but some characters outside of the Latin1 charset must have been lost when originally saved to the database. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your database is MySQL. Did you update the encoding and try? First check if you can get it to show up inside MySQL correctly. Set the encoding/collation to UTF-8, query using phpmyadmin or MySQL CLI and check how it looks.

Comment: Yes, MySQL database. What should I update the encoding to? I think I am working on a database exported/imported as UTF-8 a few times. I have tried CLI MySQL and get the same corrupted encoding.

Comment: The thing is, if the data that you have in MySQL lost encoding information at any point of time before being saved into the database, it will be difficult to resurrect it.

If you do an `iconv` on the data, what does it say the encoding is?